# How to get number of bytes that FileChannel.transferFrom wrote during it's writting

Tags: java, http, file-io

```
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
ReadableByteChannel rbc = Channels.newChannel(conn.getInputStream());   
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
FileChannel fch = fos.getChannel();
fch.transferFrom(rbc, 0, Long.MAX_VALUE);
```

I debugged it and reaches the next line of code after the download is completed.
How can I get the number of bytes that `transferFrom()` wrote during it's writing a file, to write it to a log or to the console?

Something like this

```
while (len = fch.getWriteBytes()) {
 System.out.println(len + " bytes : " + (len/total)*100 + "%");
}
```

Sorry for incomplete question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As describe in the [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html#transferFrom%28java.nio.channels.ReadableByteChannel,%20long,%20long%29), you should write:

```
long bytes = fch.transferFrom(rbc, 0, Long.MAX_VALUE);
```

Then, `bytes` will contain the number of bytes actually transferred (note: this can be zero).

**EDIT:**

The `transferFrom()` is an OS-level function and therefore can't really be monitored directly from the `FileChannel`class.

[This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11068356/416300) seems to have a good approach - wrapping the `ReadableByteChannel` class to monitor the `read()` calls.

Comment: I add more description for my question.